# Creating an executable file to download a file, then upload the file to new location

Tags: ftp, cmd, scheduled-tasks, exe, intranet

I'm having trouble finding the correct method to accomplish a relatively simple task

I'm trying to make a simple executable that I can run/schedule to run.

That 
1. Downloads a file from an intranet location (192.168.100.112/file.txt)
2. Uploads the new version file to web (fpt.website.com/docs/file.txt)

There are 5 pdf files that auto generate on an intranet and I would like to keep the web versions updated.  Ideally create one executable that does all 5 files at once and have the ability to do each one individually.

thanks

Comment: Sorry, Operating System is Windows 7. The files are not sensitive information and the web versions are for public use.Intranet file is accessable directly using the address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the windows ftp command. Is has a -s option for providing ftp "scripts". Basically just add all the commands you need to accomplish your task to something.txt for example:

```
open 192.168.100.112 
get file.txt
close
open fpt.website.com
cd docs
put file.txt
close
bye
```

then do:

```
ftp -s:something.txt
```

You could make ftp scripts, one for each upload. Then put all five commands in a batch file